# Creating a Timer which shows time left for an event in seconds , minutes , hours , days

Tags: android, countdowntimer

```
Hello I am trying to create a timer wherein it will take the date and time of the event that will happen and convert it into milliseconds and also it will take current time and then subtract the current time from the event time and will calculate the hour minutes seconds and days from it. What I want to do is display those values in a textview but as and when I try and set it in textview it stops working and gives error : - 

    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.indianic.planivore/com.indianic.planivore.view.OnSelectingAnEventFromList}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x38
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x38
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at com.indianic.planivore.view.OnSelectingAnEventFromList.onCreate(OnSelectingAnEventFromList.java:97)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  ... 11 more
```

My Code for the Layout is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#B7B1B1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageOfAnEventAfterSelection"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewOfAnEvent"
        android:src="@drawable/img_location_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shareTheEvent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageOfAnEventAfterSelection"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/shareOnSocialNetwork"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shareicon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/getSomeInformationOfEvent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageOfAnEventAfterSelection"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shareTheEvent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/getSomeInformation"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_information" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/setItToTheFavouriteIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageOfAnEventAfterSelection"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/getSomeInformationOfEvent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/favouriteIconbactch"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_starbatchicon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageOfAnEventAfterSelection"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_clock"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgCollenDays"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/collonSign"
                android:src="@drawable/collen" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberOfDays"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/defaultNull"
                android:textColor="#E50303"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgCollenDays"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/days"
                android:textColor="#05660F" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgCollenHours"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/collonSign"
                android:src="@drawable/collen" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberOfHours"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/defaultNull"
                android:textColor="#E50303"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgCollenHours"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/hours"
                android:textColor="#05660F" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgCollenMinutes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/collonSign"
                android:src="@drawable/collen" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberOfMinutes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/defaultNull"
                android:textColor="#E50303"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgCollenMinutes"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/minutes"
                android:textColor="#05660F" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberOfSeconds"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/defaultNull"
                android:textColor="#E50303"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/numberOfSeconds"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/seconds"
                android:textColor="#05660F" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/chatEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:hint="@string/EventTextView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Java File related to the same is as below Also I had tried with fragment but it is not working where am I going wrong any help any try is welcome whether its right or wrong but I will try any Idea :-

```
package com.indianic.planivore.view;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.indianic.planivore.R;

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public class OnSelectingAnEventFromList extends Activity {

    String date;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    Date eventDate = null;
    Date eventAdditionalTime = null;
    String getEventTime, getEventDate;
    long milliSecondFromDate, milliSecondFromTime, totalmillisecond,
            currentmilliseconds;
    long timeleftinmilliseconds;
    int seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks;

    TextView tv_days, tv_hour, tv_minutes, tv_seconds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.event_postselection_layout);
//  @Override
//  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    //      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//      View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_postselection_layout,
//              container, false);

        // Here getting findVievbyID of all the text view to set the time left.
        tv_days = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberOfDays);
        tv_hour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberOfHours);
        tv_minutes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberOfMinutes);
        tv_seconds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberOfSeconds);
        Log.d("PRINTING THE DAYS", tv_days.getText().toString());

        Bundle getdata = getIntent().getExtras();

        getEventTime = getdata.getString("timeleftkey");
        getEventDate = getdata.getString("datekey");
        Log.d("kjgkjnbjnknlj", getEventDate + "   " + getEventTime);
        //tv_days.setText("YO");
        // Here I am doing is that the time that I am getting I am converting it
        // to milliseconds so I will add it to the millisecond of the date and
        // will display it in the time left.
        try {
            eventAdditionalTime = time.parse(getEventTime);
            milliSecondFromTime = eventAdditionalTime.getTime();

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            eventDate = dateFormat.parse(getEventDate);
            milliSecondFromDate = eventDate.getTime();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        totalmillisecond = milliSecondFromDate + milliSecondFromTime;
        Log.d("milliSecondFromDate", "" + milliSecondFromDate);
        Log.d("milliSecondFromTime", "" + milliSecondFromTime);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        currentmilliseconds = cal.getTime().getTime();

        if (currentmilliseconds <= totalmillisecond) {

            while(currentmilliseconds <= totalmillisecond){

                timeleftinmilliseconds = totalmillisecond - currentmilliseconds;
                seconds = (int) (timeleftinmilliseconds / 1000);

                // This below will give me seconds left.
                minutes = seconds / 60;
                seconds = seconds - minutes * 60;
                tv_seconds.setText(seconds);

                // This below will give me minutes left.
                hours = minutes / 60;
                minutes = minutes - hours * 60;
                tv_minutes.setText(minutes);

                // This below will give me hours left.
                days = hours / 24;
                hours = hours - days * 24;
                tv_hour.setText(hours);

                // This below will give me days left.
                weeks = days / 7;
                days = days - weeks * 7;
                tv_days.setText(days);


            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(OnSelectingAnEventFromList.this, "LOL YOU MISSED IT", 5000).show();
        }

//      return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Also will I need a thread to handle this.And is this possible with fragment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your ints seconds, minutes and hours and so on are treated as resources. textView.setText() has two signatures, one takes a String, one an int to look up a resource. That's why you get the error  :

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x38
03-25 17:06:03.166: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
```

You have to convert them to a String like this

```
String.valueOf(days);
```

Update

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(tv);

    int hoursToGo = 0;
    int minutesToGo = 0;
    int secondsToGo = 30;

    int millisToGo = secondsToGo*1000+minutesToGo*1000*60+hoursToGo*1000*60*60;

    new CountDownTimer(millisToGo,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millis) {
            int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000) % 60 ;
            int minutes = (int) ((millis / (1000*60)) % 60);
            int hours   = (int) ((millis / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
            String text = String.format("%02d hours, %02d minutes, %02d seconds",hours,minutes,seconds);
            tv.setText(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("Kabooom");              
        }
    }.start();

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks EIDuderino and Ok but now I want to update this content of textview continuously so each second till the event date has been reached means if you see I am calculating the time left and then updating each time the text view but how can I perform that means update it each time.

Comment: Use a CountDownTimer. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: Yes I tried the countdown timer it is working but the problem is that it is not ticking each second.
The code that I had used is in the link given below : -

https://textb.org/t/e68vtaz1pt/

Comment: Actually what I am using is Fragments so what is happening is that code is running but the TextView is not getting update the reason being that in fragment we return the view and when once we return the view then that view remains static(If I am not wrong) so any solution for that...

Comment: In Activity it works but in Fragment it doesnt... Can we Load an Activity in Fragment??

Comment: It's the same as the activity, just put it in the fragments onCreateView. Of course the TextView has to be in the fragments layout... maybe read some tutorials about fragments first?